# uninitialized constant error while implementing edit in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to ruby on rails.
I was trying a new project for library management and while doing so I encountered an error,

The error I am getting is `uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Library`
when I am trying to implement edit in book_transactions.

```
Extracted source (around line #23):

20:   <div class="control-group">
21:     <%= f.label :reason_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
22:     <div class="controls">
23:       <%= collection_select(:book_transaction, :reason_id, LovHelper.getLov(Library::Library::USER_TYPE_LOV), :id, :lov_value) %>
24:     </div>
25:   </div>
26:   <div class="control-group">
```

My views is as follows:-

```
<%= form_for @book_transaction, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :book_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= collection_select(:book_transaction, :book_id, Book.all, :id, :title) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :action_date, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.datetime_select :action_date, :class => 'datetime_select' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :num_copies, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.number_field :num_copies, :class => 'number_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :reason_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= collection_select(:book_transaction, :reason_id, LovHelper.getLov(Library::Library::USER_TYPE_LOV), :id, :lov_value) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :notes, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area(:notes, :size => '80x10', :class => 'text_field')%>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :entered_by, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.number_field :entered_by, :class => 'number_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                book_transactions_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My table is as follows:-

```
id serial NOT NULL,
  book_id integer,
  action_date timestamp without time zone,
  num_copies integer,
  reason_id integer,
  notes character varying(255),
  entered_by integer,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT book_transactions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

my Lovhelper file is as follows:-

```
module LovHelper

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    #  getLov - Get a list of values for a particular LOV type
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def self.getLov(lov_type)
        lovs = LovValue.unscoped
        lovs = lovs.select('lov_values.id, lov_value')
        lovs = lovs.joins(:lov_name)
        lovs = lovs.where('lov_names.name = ? ', lov_type)
        lovs = lovs.order('sequence asc')
        lovs.all

        return lovs     
    end

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    #  getValue - Get the value pertaining to a particular LOV Value id
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def self.getValue(lov_value_id)
        lov = LovValue.find(:all,
                                :select => 'lov_value',
                                :conditions => ['id = ? ', lov_value_id]).first
        return lov.lov_value
    end

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    #  getLovNames - Get a list of LOV names
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def self.getLovNames
        lov_names = LovName.all
        return lov_names
    end

end
```

Now the code I have been given to work on is implemented by my senior so there is a little bit of problem to understand it.

Can anyone please explain it to me why I am getting this error.

Comment: We need some more information on the LOVHelper and Library::Library - what's going on here, this is the line that's not working.

Comment: @Matt even I didn't understand why we are using Library::Library.
I have added the lovhelper file in the question

Comment: Have you tried with just Library::USER_TYPE_LOV? Can you find that object/method in thje Library class?

Comment: @Matt..Library is the name of my project..I dont think there is a class called Library

Also I have tried the above already but still giving me an error

Comment: USER_TYPE_LOV exists somewhere, find it and follow the class/module/application chain up to work out where the item is located, and therefore how you need to access it. (Post the chain here if you can)

Comment: @Matt I got the file in the controller,but I don't know what to do.
It was commented ,now i removed the comment and it is giving

uninitialized constant error...can you tell me how to initialize it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26715/discussion-between-matt-and-peevee)

Comment: @Matt please come in chat